# python post запрос не приходит смс

Tags: python, post, request

Пытаюсь отправить post запрос на сайт, при запросе получается код 200, но смс не приходит. Вот код запроса

```
    headers = {"user-agent": user}
    a = (requests.post('https://my-shop.ru/cgi-bin/my_util2.pl?q=my_code_for_phone_confirmation&view_id=bcffe5c5-92e5-4afc-bab4-78202af33769ca34603c7', headers=headers, data = {"phone_code":"7","phone":"2355435345"}, params = {'q':'my_co

de_for_phone_confirmation','view_id':'bcffe5c5-92e5-4afc-bab4-78202af33769ca34603c7'}))
```

[image: Вот так выглядит payload]
Какие данные еще нужно добавить в запрос, чтобы он сработал

Comment: Мож какиe небудь хейдеров не хватает, может куки требуется, может data должна отправляться как JSON.

Comment: Вам в помощь https://curlconverter.com/ инструкция прилагается на сайте.